# How to Plot a Series

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot

```
f1[x_, n_] := Sum[Sin[(2 j - 1) x]/(2 j - 1), {j, 1, n}]
```

on a single plot containing f1(x,50), f1(x,100), f1(x,1000), with three different colored lines.

Please help

Comment: Are `j` and `k` equal?! What `x` should be?

Comment: Yes, j and k and equal. I must've input k instead of j at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f1[x_, n_] := Sum[Sin[(2 j - 1) x]/(2 j - 1), {j, 1, n}]; 
Plot[ f1[x, #] & /@ {50, 100, 1000}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me to understand what the input "f1[x, #] & /@ {50, 100, 1000}" means? Specifically the "#" and "& /@"

Comment: @MathStudent, `f1[x, #] & /@ {50, 100, 1000}` is shorter way of writing `{f1[x, 50],f1[x,100],f1[x,1000]}`. See docs on [Slot (#)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) and [Map (/@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html)

Comment: Nice plot, it shows the Gibbs phenomenon clearly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this the correct function:

```
f1[x_, n_] := Sum[Sin[(2 k - 1) x]/(2 k - 1), {k, 1, n}];
```

We can plot them by the following command:

```
Plot[f1[x, #] & /@ {50, 100, 1000}, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"50", "100", "1000"}, {1.01, 0.5}]]
```

or equivalently:

```
Plot[{f1[x,50],f1[x,100],f1[x,1000]}, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"50", "100", "1000"}, {1.01, 0.5}]]
```

for 0 to $\pi$.

[image]

Comment: Your second plotting input is much easier to understand, where you commanded each of the plots. May you help me to understand what "{1.01, 0.5}" means?

Comment: Yes! I use `Placed` command to put the legend at {1.01,0.5}. `Mathematica` assumes that the figure coordinates is {0,1} horizontally and vertically. So for example if write {0.5,0.5} legend will be right at the middle of figure.